# Lenovo X250 - Wifi Connection drops constantly - Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, lenovo, intel-wireless, iwlwifi

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo X250 and I experience frequent drops of my WIFI connection. After the connection has gone down I can still see my network's name in the list of available networks. All other publicly visible networks are gone, however. If I try to reconnect nothing happens. Only a suspend or a restart solves the problem. Here is the output of `lshw -C network`:

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (3) I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       logical name: eth1
       version: 03
       serial: 68:f7:28:64:1b:9d
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=e1000e latency=0 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:20 memory:f1200000-f121ffff memory:f123e000-f123efff ioport:3080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan1
       version: 59
       serial: 60:57:18:75:fe:c7
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-53-generic firmware=22.24.8.0 ip=192.168.178.30 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:64 memory:f1000000-f1001fff
```

I'm running the kernel version: 3.13.0-53. I once updated to kernel 4.1 and I had the impression that wifi disconnects were less frequent or gone completely but I experienced very high CPU temps and the fan was running constantly.

Can anyone help, please?